# Changing background in banner

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/95arxd46/) is the code I'm working on.

HTML

```
<section id="banner">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-XKyf-av-Cq4/T8iF9hnSOII/AAAAAAAATUg/zeO5BrKvSes/s1600/tiaras+princesas,novias+(3).png" alt="" style="max-width:200px;height:auto" />
    <br>
    <h2>Etiam adipiscing</h2>
    <p>Magna feugiat lorem dolor egestas</p>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><a href="#" class="button big special">Learn More</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#banner {
    padding: 8em 0 6em 0;
    background-color: #662800;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("../images/banner.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

#banner input, #banner select, #banner textarea {
    color: #fff;
}

#banner a {
    color: #FF6600;
}
```

Which is the easiest way to make background (images) of the slider to change without any action every 2-3 seconds? I did my research, tried to include [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4d2N7/) with some modifications, but it's not working. I'm not really sure how to modify existing CSS in the right way, and how my HTML should look in the end.

Any idea how to make that work? Is there any easier way?

Comment: Check this out and get the basic idea.! A simple CSS based [slider](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to just have the background change, without any kind of interaction, [here's an adaptation of the other fiddle you were trying to get working.](http://jsfiddle.net/95arxd46/4/)

```
var images = [ "http://domain.com/imageoneurl.jpg", "http://domain.com/imagetwourl.jpg"];
```

Include all the images you want to cycle through in the above array, separated by commas, in quotation marks.

Below we're setting a variable for the banner element, as well as the interval time in milliseconds.

```
var bannerBackground = document.getElementById( 'banner' );
var interval = 2500; //in milliseconds
```

Below the actual magic is happening. We're popping off the last image and setting the `background-image` property to the first image in the array, and repeating every 2500 milliseconds. You can adjust that timer by changing the number in the `var interval =` declaration.

```
setInterval( function(){
  images.unshift( images.pop() );
  bannerBackground.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + "'" + images[0] + "'" + ")";
 }, interval );
```

No modifications need to be made to your HTML itself, you do need to include this JavaScript somehow though. Either paste it all into a `.js` file and include it that way at the bottom of your document, or paste it into the document itself, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// self executing function
(function() {
   // paste all your JavaScript code here.

})();

</script>
```

Paste this at the bottom, right above your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: I have one more question, how to limit image size to 95% percent of the screen size? I tried to limit banner, but it's not working properly on smaller screen sizes.